Problem of Affection in Kant's Thing in themselves as Causes, Neo Kantians and Post Kantians Responses
We all know "the problem of affection" raised by Schulze:
"if causality is apriori structure of the mind and exist inside the mind, how can we claim thing-in-themselves cause phenomena when thing-in-themselves are outside the mind?"
How did Neo Kantians and Post Kantians like Hermann Cohen and Ernst Cassirer and Schopenhauer and Heidegger! responded to this issue?
I only know that Schopenhauer claim that (unlike kant) thing-in-themselves can be known to some extend, for example Schopenhauer says Will is the thing-in itself. And it seems like Cohen claims that our Sensibility isn't passive but active as well in creating the Phenomena, I haven't read much about him so i don't know whether he would reject the existence of Thing-in-themselves or like Schopenhauer would claim that it exist but it can be known to some extend.
But I don't understand how these are relevant to "the problem of affection".
Does anybody know their arguments? Is there any book or website that talks about these things?

Marburg Neo-Kantian responses are not interesting because they simply discarded the unknowable thing-in-itself, like Fichte and Hegel did earlier. IEP reviews more interesting responses that try to stay closer to Kant. They either suggest that the affectors are not things-in-themselves but "mind-independent appearances" (Bird, Prauss) or relax the unknowability thesis. Allison makes them "thinkable" with affection in some "logical" sense, Chignel and Watkins  distinguish knowledge and cognition, etc.

I wonder if this is related to recent questions of Identity and Uniqueness?

Re. "how can we claim thing-in-themselves cause phenomena"?
The thing-in-itself that causes a phenomenon is simply unknown beyond appearance, that's the problem.  It's not that it doesn't exist (notionally), it's just that one doesn't know at all what is it in order to make a judgement on it, which is what would make it objectively exist in the Kantian sense. I.e. note 36 B287 :

"[existence] is the conjunction of the [notional] thing with perception."

Re. "Schopenhauer says Will is the thing-in itself"
The one thing-in-itself that one can know is oneself.  However, previously the topic was objective existence.  Now this is subjective existence, aka Being, so the goal posts are shifting unreasonably.
Heidegger discusses affection—that which causes an effect—in Kant and the Problem of Metaphysics.  Since the "I" of cogito ergo sum is self-contained any source of effect must come from the self.  That is to say, in Descartes' pared-back cogito, the assumption is that it is complete in itself.  So all source of effects come from itself.  In its own movement it creates time.

Time is, by nature, pure affection of itself. (Kantbuch, p. 194)

There is nothing 'outside' Descartes' ego cogito that it is affected by, as by definition.

Therefore, it is absolutely untrue that the mind exists in such a way
that, among other beings, it relates certain things to itself and in
so doing posits itself [Selbstsetzungen ausübt]. Rather, this line
of orientation from the self toward . . . and back to [the self] first
constitutes the mental character of the mind as a finite self.
It is at once obvious, therefore, that time as pure self-affection is
not found "in the mind" "beside" pure apperception. On the contrary,
as the basis of the possibility of selfhood, time is already included
in pure apperception and first enables the mind to be what it is. (Kantbuch, p. 196-7)

